# Finished execution of Membership status processor with result: Failure, Error message: Invalid data value given

Tags: civimember, scheduled-job

Drupal 7.x and CiviCRM 5.52.2

Full error:

> Aug 09 10:19:30  [debug] $Query = INSERT INTO `civicrm_job_log`
> (`domain_id` , `job_id` , `name` , `command` , `description` , `data`
> ) VALUES ( 1 ,  11 , 'Membership status processor' , 'Entity: Job
> Action: process_membership' , 'Finished execution of Membership status
> processor with result: Failure, Error message: Invalid data value
> given. Be sure it matches the required data type and format. Value at
> civicrm_line_item(): .' , '\n\nParameters parsed (and passed to API
> method): \na:1:{s:7:"version";i:3;}\n\nFull message: \nFinished
> execution of Membership status processor with result: Failure, Error
> message: Invalid data value given. Be sure it matches the required
> data type and format. Value at civicrm_line_item(): .' )

When looking at the CiviCRM.sql_log this was the full error. Any tips about how I could continue to debug?

ConfigAndLog has warnings such as the following when the job is attempted

```
127409  Aug 09 12:05:32 [warning] hook_civicrm_alter_drupal_entities should be updated to pass an array of parameter names to CRM_Utils_Hook::invoke(). Caller: ::_civicrm_enabled_entity_alter_whitelist
127402  Aug 09 12:05:32 [warning] hook_civicrm_entity_supported_info should be updated to pass an array of parameter names to CRM_Utils_Hook::invoke(). Caller: ::civicrm_entity_get_supported_entity_info
127395  Aug 09 12:05:32 [warning] hook_civicrm_alter_drupal_entities should be updated to pass an array of parameter names to CRM_Utils_Hook::invoke(). Caller: ::_civicrm_enabled_entity_alter_whitelist
127388  Aug 09 12:05:32 [warning] hook_civicrm_entity_supported_info should be updated to pass an array of parameter names to CRM_Utils_Hook::invoke(). Caller: ::civicrm_entity_get_supported_entity_info
127381  Aug 09 12:05:32 [warning] hook_civicrm_alter_drupal_entities should be updated to pass an array of parameter names to CRM_Utils_Hook::invoke(). Caller: ::_civicrm_enabled_entity_alter_whitelist
127374  Aug 09 12:05:32 [warning] hook_civicrm_entity_supported_info should be updated to pass an array of parameter names to CRM_Utils_Hook::invoke(). Caller: ::civicrm_entity_get_supported_entity_info
127367  Aug 09 12:05:32 [warning] hook_civicrm_alter_drupal_entities should be updated to pass an array of parameter names to CRM_Utils_Hook::invoke(). Caller: ::_civicrm_enabled_entity_alter_whitelist
127360  Aug 09 12:05:32 [warning] hook_civicrm_entity_supported_info should be updated to pass an array of parameter names to CRM_Utils_Hook::invoke(). Caller: ::civicrm_entity_get_supported_entity_info
127353  Aug 09 12:05:32 [warning] hook_civicrm_alter_drupal_entities should be updated to pass an array of parameter names to CRM_Utils_Hook::invoke(). Caller: ::_civicrm_enabled_entity_alter_whitelist
127346  Aug 09 12:05:32 [warning] hook_civicrm_entity_supported_info should be updated to pass an array of parameter names to CRM_Utils_Hook::invoke(). Caller: ::civicrm_entity_get_supported_entity_info
127339  Aug 09 12:05:31 [warning] hook_civicrm_alter_drupal_entities should be updated to pass an array of parameter names to CRM_Utils_Hook::invoke(). Caller: ::_civicrm_enabled_entity_alter_whitelist
127332  Aug 09 12:05:31 [warning] hook_civicrm_entity_supported_info should be updated to pass an array of parameter names to CRM_Utils_Hook::invoke(). Caller: ::civicrm_entity_get_supported_entity_info
127325  Aug 09 12:05:31 [warning] hook_civicrm_alter_drupal_entities should be updated to pass an array of parameter names to CRM_Utils_Hook::invoke(). Caller: ::_civicrm_enabled_entity_alter_whitelist
127318  Aug 09 12:05:31 [warning] hook_civicrm_entity_supported_info should be updated to pass an array of parameter names to CRM_Utils_Hook::invoke(). Caller: ::civicrm_entity_get_supported_entity_info
127311  Aug 09 12:05:31 [warning] hook_civicrm_alter_drupal_entities should be updated to pass an array of parameter names to CRM_Utils_Hook::invoke(). Caller: ::_civicrm_enabled_entity_alter_whitelist
127304  Aug 09 12:05:31 [warning] hook_civicrm_entity_supported_info should be updated to pass an array of parameter names to CRM_Utils_Hook::invoke(). Caller: ::civicrm_entity_get_supported_entity_info
127297  Aug 09 12:05:31 [warning] hook_civicrm_alter_drupal_entities should be updated to pass an array of parameter names to CRM_Utils_Hook::invoke(). Caller: ::_civicrm_enabled_entity_alter_whitelist
127290  Aug 09 12:05:31 [warning] hook_civicrm_entity_supported_info should be updated to pass an array of parameter names to CRM_Utils_Hook::invoke(). Caller: ::civicrm_entity_get_supported_entity_info
```

Answer (score 1):

The installed version of https://www.drupal.org/project/civicrm_entity was out of date. I solved the issue by upgrading the module to civicrm_entity 7.x-2.4